# Tumblr Issues with Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tumblr

I can't seem to figure out what is causing an issue with my navigation bar.

Here's the problem. The navigation does not become static (fixed to the top), nor do the drop down links work as they do on the main site.

If you take a look at http://devildogusainc.org you'll notice how the navigation bar functions. When you visit http://blog.devildogusainc.org it is completely broken. The drown down menu's do not function, nor does the navigation bar affix to the top when it reaches X pixels when the page is scrolled.

Any help is welcomed and if needed I can clarify my problems if confused.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found this error on my console **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null in main.js:40"**

check your javascripts includes.

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look into this. I don't even think that I have a main.js file...

Comment: Thanks, that was it. It was toward the bottom of my document, something I simply overlooked.